No stdin read in python when piped from Get-Content -Wait
I'm trying to combine a powershell Get-Content -Wait command with a simple python script like so:
Get-Content -Wait log_file.log | python app_that_reads_stdin.py

the trouble is, in my python script, sys.stdin never iterates. This behavior is not seen without the -Wait argument to Get-Content
the relevant python code is:
for line_number, message in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    # stuff

I expected each line written to the file after the Get-Content command was executed to be sent to stdout, where it could be read from stdin in python.
this all works fine with tail -f on *nux, and without the -Wait flag in powershell, so I'm fairly convinced this is a peculiarity of this powershell comandlet.
What am I doing wrong? Is there another way I can approximate tail -f on Windows?

This works. Get-Content -Path .\FileEntry.cs -Wait | python -c "import sys; [sys.stdout.write(line) for line in sys.stdin]"

mmm i can replicate the issue in powershell 5.1 :( for now i'd recommend using pwsh 7+

I cannot repro any output using Get-Content -Path .\FileEntry.cs -Wait | python -c "import sys; [sys.stdout.write(line) for line in sys.stdin].

definitely a bug in 5.1 with -Wait. If you install latest pwsh 7 problem solved :) https://i.imgur.com/UDuD24r.png

confirmed this works as expected with poweshell 7.4.2; seems to be specific to ps 5.1

I guess you could post that as the answer to your question :) I don't think you can get a solution to the problem in 5.1 unless you wanna write your own take of Get-Content -Wait using the .NET apis

Get current on PowerShell for Linux, Mac, and Windows at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

So this seems to work fine in powershell 7, but doesn't seem to work in windows powershell for some reason, even though the docs say it should. What you can do instead is a tail with a while loop that checks if the content read is the same as the content already there for the last line, with the tail switch.
$previous = ""
While($True){
  $line = Get-Content -Tail 1 log_file.log
  if($previous -ne $line){
    $line | python printstdin.py
    $previous = $line
  }
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

It's a bit more complex, but it gets the job done.
Or, you could have it check line numbers instead.
$i = 0 
While($True){
  $content = Get-Content log_file.log
  $line_count = ($content | Measure-Object).count
  if($line_count -ge $i){
    $content | Select -Skip $i -First ($line_count - $i) | python printstdin.py
    $i += ($line_count - $i)
  }
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

This approach would catch everything, regardless of if multiple lines were added before the file refreshed.
Or, you could just do it in python, and avoid the oddities of working between them.
